# What Is Used At Your Company For A Secure FTP Server?

Tags: ftp

I am trying to make a decision about FTP servers and would like to know what is being used at companies and what the experiences with the server was?

I am specifically looking at enterprise-sized companies.

Comment: "Enterprise-sized companies"?  FTP servers?  Gah!

Comment: Just to clarfiy, when you say secure, do you mean FTP over SSH (aka "Secure FTP") or do you just mean a hardened FTP server?

Comment: What kind of secure FTP have you considered? Other options are FTPES (FTP over explicit TLS/SSL) and FTPS (FTP over implicit TLS/SSL).

Answer (score 5):

We're using vsftpd on linux. Department at a large university with ~ 50k undergrads.

Comment: What are you using as the authentication on that?

Comment: Depends on the use. Some are just using SSL certs / shared keys; some are using passwords that eventually register back with a central LDAP server.

Answer (score 3):

For Windows environments, IIS7+ with the [new FTP module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/310/what-is-new-for-microsoft-and-ftp-75/) (not included by default in IIS7.0) which supports FTP over SSL.

But no, ftp in any form is not used ^^

Answer (score 1):

Serv-U on Windows. A few hundred clients. Seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

Vsftpd to provide ftp services.

We have just started providing SFTP/SCP access using [rssh](http://dragontoe.org/rssh/). Been working out quite well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use VSFTPD as FTP server
The thing I like is the ability to chroot users. So they only see their own direcotry.
Every time you add a new user, he's quickly able to use his FTP client to connect to his home.
Do you need extra features ? like stats for instance

Answer (score 1):

We have been using crushFTP for some months.  Has worked very well for about 125 users.  Small footprint and stable.  Too many features to detail here.

http://www.crushftp.com

Answer (score 0):

At my last gig we used vsftpd on ~2 frontend "ftp" servers that accessed a SAN, which in turn powered ~40 frontend webservers.  A couple thousand clients.

Answer (score 0):

We're using Pure FTPD with chroot, but with no encryption.

Sensitive data is not put on the FTP, so I'm okay with it :)

Answer (score 0):

Proftpd with TLS module :)

Answer (score 0):

ssh...transfer using Fugu on Macs and Filezilla on Linux/Windows as the clients.

There is no way to really have plain "FTP" be secure as the username/password are sent in cleartext.

You might want to investigate using a form of WebDAV for easy file transfers to clients; if this is something in a business on the internal LAN, why isn't a file share possible?

otherwise, vsftpd has worked fairly well in the past, but again we're not slapping much for sharing up there because it is insecure as a protocol and we normally resort to shares via SAMBA/native Windows to get files moved around.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend this software if you are looking for a free ssh file transfer system(windows)

http://www.bitvise.com/winsshd

I was using winOpenSSH but it crashed one time, and even after 3-4 reinstalls it never started working again. And I didn't have the patience to really figure out was going wrong, seemed like the ssh worked, but then the sftp server service was down after authentication.

Anyway, this system seems pretty impressive, and very easy to use.

If you pay for it, it does active directory and fun stuff like that too.

Answer (score 0):

We're using PureFTPd on FreeBSD. Very configurable and demands very little resources to run in our environment.

Answer (score 0):

At work, we use vsftpd and proftpd (with TLS). Both work fine for us. Several hundred users.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be considered "ftp" but I use [WWW FileShare Pro](http://www.wfshome.com/) where I work.  It allows us to set up accounts for clients that can't install FTP software.  All that's needed on the client end is an internet browser.  There are only 20 people working here but we have many clients.  I've set up a spare computer as the "server" and mapped the client account folder as a network drive so anyone can put put files into their client's folders for download.